# Resized bitmap's width and height are not the same as resized bitmap draw on canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, width, scale

I have a image,and now i want to resize this image,so I use matrix to realize it.But when I draw this resized bitmap on canvas,Here is my code...I finally found that the rect I draw is smaller than the resized bitmap draw on canvas.I don't know why :(

```
    Matrix m=new Matrix();
    m.setScale(ratio,ratio);
    m.postRotate(Angle,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
    newbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m,true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(newbitmap,0,0, null);
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,newbitmap.getWidth(),newbitmap.getHeight(), paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to to do is try using the same height and width of the created bitmap while drawing it on the canvas.Sometimes it may become right.This piece of code may help you.

```
Bitmap Rbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap).copy(
                Config.ARGB_4444, true);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Rbitmap);

        canvas.drawBitmap(label, -9, Rbitmap.getHeight()-label.getHeight()-10, null);
        canvas.save();
```